# Creating an efficient WebRTC P2P Connection

Tags: java, android, webrtc, p2p, kurento

I'm using Kurento ([more specifically, this example](http://doc-webrtcpeer-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/DevelopersGuide.html#)) to create a P2P app on Android.

I intend to deliver large files with this app. Problem is, with this example, a separate datachannel is opened for every peer connected to the "host". This would be simply unusable - incompatible with the average user's upload speed.

So, I want to create a topology sort of like common torrent P2P apps - every peer connected contributes their upload speed to the peer group.

How can I implement this?

Thanks a ton in advance!